# How to view history for all Git commits/changes for a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I can right click on a file using the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2017 and View History which shows all the history of the changes for that file.

I would like to do the same at the solution or project node and view all the changes for all the files. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

In the Changes window, you can view the repo history under the Actions dropdown:

[image: Showing the Actions context menu with "View History" highlighted]

Comment: When there are no changes, there's no context menu. It seems you right clicked on that file. View History shows history for that file only. I want a rolling history for ALL the files that changed over time.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @Jimmy answer you can stay within Solution Explorer by switching it to show the Folders view.  Then you can right click on the top of the folder tree and select View History.

[image: Solution Explorer - Folders]

[image: Right Click - View History]

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2019, Git features have been moved. You can view all the commits for a repo from the Git branch history window. You can access it from the Git menu in the main menu bar:

```
Git ➔ View Branch History
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for VS 2019 and above, using the Git Changes tab - Clicking "Manage Branches" will open up the "Local History" view:

[image]